Are there any rules of thumb for when membership of a group gets its own name?
So for context, I'm in a team translating a work from Japanese, and we're coming across a bunch of oddly named groups. We're finding ourselves in disagreement on when and why members of a group can or can't be referred to by the group name.
To illustrate, let's use band names.
The band (the group) is the Beatles, while an individual in the band could be called "a Beatle."
On the other hand you might have Led Zeppelin, where individuals aren't called "a Led Zeppelin". They would have to be referred to as "members of Led Zeppelin", or "Led Zeppelin musicians."
So far we've gone based on gut feeling, but we've run into edge cases where we disagree on what sounds natural. Is there any guideline for when this works and when it doesn't? For instance...
Does the name need familiarity or some form of cultural precedent?
Does it primarily work for groups with a plural as the name? (i.e. Beatles or Beastie Boys might work, while Metallica or Rush don't. Then again, it probably wouldn't work for the Rolling Stones or the Doors despite them being plural)
Is there no name for the members by default unless it fulfills some criteria?

In English, we say band members. Or band member [name of person].

Band names are not typically used to refer to individual members, although "I was a Rolling Stone" would be understood in context. For others: "I am a Door" and "I am a Beach Boy" don't work.

I think "a Beatle" is an ideosyncratic case where it's allowed, you can't generalize from it to other band names. There's a classic lyric "Poppa was a rolling stone", it doesn't mean he was a member of the band. But as @WeatherVane says, "Mick Jagger is a Rolling Stone" and "Brian Wilson is a Beach Boy" would be understood.

Don't think too hard; you really can't go wrong if you consistently say a member of...

There are a lot of instances of Beach Boy in the singular Rolling Stone, People, TV documentary, etc, and many other band names in the singular (TV doc Mick Jagger: My Life As a Rolling Stone, Beastie Boy, etc). The rule is simply to avoid being ambiguous, awkward, or unintentionally humorous. It's fine in journalism, as my examples show, but maybe not in very formal writing.

Obviously, ridiculous examples should be avoided. *a Mama and Papa / *a Black Eyed Pea / *a Guns N' Rose / *a Pip  /  *a Smashing Pumpkin / *a Tears for Fear / *a [Long John Baldry & The] Hoochie Coochie Man / *a Pigeon Playing Ping Pong / ??a Bunnyman / ??a  Dire Strait / ?a Nine Inch Nail ...

Hey, hey, I'm a Monkee,
and people say I monkey around.
But I'm too busy singing,
to put anybody down.
It's not for everybody.

My rule of thumb would be what seemed to fit me ear.
Screaming Lord Sutch is fairly-well known for founding the Official Monster Raving Loony Party.
Does that make his followers 'Screamers' or 'Lords' or 'Sutches' or 'Officials' or 'Monsters' or 'Ravers' or 'Loonies'?
As a neutral I myself might boil that down to 'Screamers' or 'Sutches' or 'Ravers' but his detractors would prolly choose 'Loonies'
